# How do I get the value of a div inside a div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to figure out how to either set the ID of the last Div, or get the value of the last DIV.  I can't use the classes below, as they're used over & over in the code.  Perhaps nodechilds of the main one?

I've tried searching around, with no luck.

```
<div class="designer-object adapter" id="73c8f274-e14f-4891-126e-67019bb100d1" data-previewcolor="" zindex="10008" style="width: 140px; height: 22px; left: 916px; top: 90px; z-index: 10008; opacity: 1;">
  <div class="labelControl">
    <div class="labelControlLabel" style="overflow: visible;">
      <div class="labelControlLabelTable">
        <div class="labelControlLabelCell" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">System Administrator</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Need to return value `System Administrator`

Comment: well how do you know what element to select if classes reused everywhere? What is triggering you to have to get the value?

Comment: Yes, children of the main one if necessary/possible.

Comment: Do you want the last DIV or the main one? How do you define which one is "main"?

Comment: I'm looking to return the value System Administrator, from the last DIV.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can scope your query selector by either invoking `querySelector` on a particular `node` rather than `document`, or by using the child (`a b`) or descendant (`a>b`) selectors.

Secondly, to get the text of a div, simply read the `textContent` property.

```js
let parentId = '73c8f274-e14f-4891-126e-67019bb100d1';
let text = document.querySelector(`#${parentId} .labelControlLabelCell`).textContent;
console.log(text); // System Administrator
```

Comment: This didn't work:  
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#73c8f274-e14f-4891-126e-67019bb100d1.labelControlLabelCell' is not a valid selector.
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous>

Comment: That's because element Id's must start with a-z.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `getElementsByClassName()` and use an index. Here is a good [Good explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) for what it is. When using it, `document.getElementsByClassName("labelControlLabelCell")[index]` where `index` is number of the div, starting from 0. So you have to do some counting but it works.

Comment: The problem is there are multiple "labelControlLabelCell" div's & I need a way to dynamically assign them, so that if the code changes later, I'm not pointing to the "4th" one.  So, I need to use the ID of the first one as a jumping point to maybe then navigate down to the 4th DIV & grab the textContent from there.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign an id to the element as below:

```
<div class="labelControlLabelCell" id="dummyId" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">System Administrator</div>
```

then use following method to get the content:

```
var x = document.getElementById("dummyId").textContent;
```